# My Datatable on Laravel 5.3 sometime error

Tags: laravel

I've been using Datatable on my Laravel project, but sometime when I refresh the page, it works and sometime it doesnt

This is my script on view

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var oTable = $('#tabel-stok').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                order: [[ 0 ,"desc"]],
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ url("data-stok") }}'
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'nama_produk', name: 'nama_produk'},
                    {data: 'harga_satuan', name: 'harga_satuan'},
                    {data: 'jumlah_stok', name: 'jumlah_stok'},
                    {data: 'tambah', name: 'tambah', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                    {data: 'edit', name: 'edit', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ],
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

This is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('transaksi-masuk.transaksi-masuk');
    }

    public function dataStok()
    {
        $stok = Produk::all();
        return Datatables::of($stok)
            ->addColumn('tambah', function ($stok) {
                return '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/tambah/' . $stok->id_produk . '"><span class="label label-primary">TAMBAH</span></a>';
            })
            ->addColumn('edit', function ($stok) {
                return '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/edit/' . $stok->id_produk . '"><span class="label label-warning">EDIT</span></a>';
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

And this is the error message

```
DataTables warning: table id=tabel-stok - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Is there any solution for this? Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific error response from the "data-stok" endpoint? Or at least an http response code?

Comment: you mean this? `http://localhost:8000/data-stok?draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=updated_at&…rt=20&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1495057094473 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: So the 404 means it's not finding the correct endpoint. Is `http://localhost:8000/data-stok` the correct endpoint as defined in your routes file?

Comment: Yes, this is my route 
`Route::get('/data-stok', 'TransaksiMasukController@dataStok');`

Comment: clear two addColumn and make refresh many times. does it make a problem?

Comment: I've tried that before and it works well, but when I using two addColumn it becomes error sometime

Comment: when I using one of them it works fine too

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I tried to remove addColumn from controller and edit my script like this

```
columns: [
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'nama_produk', name: 'nama_produk'},
                    {data: 'harga_satuan', name: 'harga_satuan'},
                    {data: 'jumlah_stok', name: 'jumlah_stok'},
                    {
                        name: '',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/tambah/:id"><span class="label label-primary">TAMBAH</span></a>';
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/edit/:id"><span class="label label-warning">EDIT</span></a>';
                            return actions.replace(/:id/g, data.id_produk);
                        }
                    }
```

Thank you for helping me :)